# How can I make a heatmap with respect to data rather than lat, lon coordinates? R, Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, heatmap

I have 12,000 data points that are structured like this: (lon,lat,value). I would like to make a heatmap of this data with respect to the values but I do not want the map to be be affected by the x,y density. There are simply more measurements in some areas due to geographical constraints. I have tried the Google maps API by using weighted points but their implementation still factors in the point density. 
I would like to use Python or R to do this as I want to produce a vector format image. Currently, I only have a scatterplot of my data where the points are colored by value at that location. 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAWG5.jpg]

Ideally, the figure would look something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gppVC.png]

This is the code I have:

```
#Create a map centered on Canada
maps = Basemap(projection = "merc", resolution = "l",area_thresh = 100,
               llcrnrlon = -143, llcrnrlat = 42, urcrnrlon = -50, urcrnrlat = 79)
maps.drawmapboundary(fill_color = "aqua", zorder = 1)
maps.fillcontinents(color='white',lake_color='aqua', zorder = 3)
maps.drawcountries(zorder = 5)
maps.drawstates(zorder = 7)

data = pd.read_csv("stats_by_coordinates.csv")
import matplotlib.cm as cm

vio_norm = np.log(data['vio']) # log normalize data
maxima = max(vio_norm) 
**# Scale data between ¨0 and 1 for color mapping**
vio_norm = [x/float(maxima) for x in vio_norm] 


x = []
y = []

for i in range(len(data)):
    lon,lat = maps(data['lon'][i], data['lat'][i]) #Convert to map coordinates
    x.append(lon)
    y.append(lat)

maps.scatter(x,y,zorder = 10, marker = "o",facecolor = vio_norm, edgecolor = "",
            alpha = 1.0,c = vio_norm,s = 1,lw = 0, cmap = py.cm.YlOrRd)
py.colorbar()
py.savefig('myimage.png', format='png', dpi=1200, bbox_inches = "tight")
```

Comment: How exactly do you want the final plot to look like? What quantitiy do you want the heatmap to show? If you have problem describing it, you might want to show a picture of what you imagine. What do you mean by "I do not want the map to be be affected by the x,y density"? As it stands the question is too unclear to be answered.

Comment: What do you mean by "I do not want the map to be be affected by the x,y density"?  If my data points are (lon, lat, some value) I want the heatmap to be of that 'some value' and not affected by how close the (x,y) pairs are. Seems like a pretty clear question o me

Comment: A heatmap would need to have a certain cell size. What determines the cell size in your case? What should happen if several points are within the same cell? Also mind the questions from my first comment and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: I was expecting the cell size to be each (lon, lat) pair. Done this way there would not be multiple points in the same cell as all these pairs are unique.

Comment: (lan, lot) is a point without extention. A cell has an extention. How large should the cell be?

Comment: I had misunderstood what you meant by cell size. Could you give me advice on how I would plot the figure for some arbitrary cell size. I will have to figure out what do with multiple points if they are in the same cell, possibly I could average them

Comment: Now it seems that you do actually want a density plot (at least that is what's shown in the picture above). So I'm a bit confused now. ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry for explaining this poorly. Maybe an example will help. Lets say I'm recording precipitation levels across the country and want to make a heatmap of this data. I set a bunch of measurement devices and collect the data. There are more measurement devices in some regions and less in others. However, when I make the precipitation heatmap I wouldn't want the it to somehow reflect the relative density of the measuring devices.

Comment: What about using a [`hexbin`](http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plotting_data.html#hexbin) plot?